# Find the number of open Opportunities

Tags: trigger, controller

I want to find the number of open opportunities related with Account object and autofill the custom field of Account object with the numbers of open opportunity...

Comment: Is this a once off data load?

Comment: no..its just populating a field on account object

Comment: i want to perform this task using trigger not via rollup summary

Comment: @rahulseth Any particular reason why you want to use trigger and not rollupsummary? Regarding the trigger, you will need to write a trigger on Opportunity for insert, update, delete and undelete events. You might find it useful to use an aggregrate query on Opportunity with IsClosed = false to get the count for account.

Comment: no,as roll up summary is very easy way to perform the task but i want to perform this task using trigger also...

Answer (score 3):

Try to follow the following process

```
  Setup -> Account -> Create new Field -> Roll-Up Summary -> Name The field - > 
  Select Summarized Object ( Opportunities), then select "COUNT" - >
  Select Filter Criteria "Only records meeting certain criteria should be included in the calculation" ->
  For the field select Closed ; For the Operator select equals ; For the Value type "false"
```

Additionally for the field you could select `"Stage"` ; Operator: `"contains"`; Value: `all the open stage values separated by a coma`

Comment: I want to perform this task using trigger

Comment: If you only require this functionality I suggest you to try to solve it using, roll-ups, workflows, formulas as they are easier to maintain across your org

Comment: @rahulseth if you want to try with trigger then pls first try yourself, if you face any issue while that time then let us know here.

Answer (score 0):

So you can have a trigger which get fired when Opportunity record is created.

You can try this.

```
for(AggregateResult oppRec : [SELECT Count(Id) oppCount, Name FROM Opportunity Where AccountID =: AccountID_In_Inserted_Opportunity and Status = 'open' GROUP BY Account]){
   custom_Field_For_Saving_Count = oppRec.oppCount // This will get your the count of Opportunity related to particulate Account.  
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: thanxxx... iam checking with it

Comment: i think this is for only creation of opportunity..and not for updation and deletion

Comment: plzz help with all the three scenarios

Comment: You don't need to change anything just need to add after update, after insert, after delete in your trigger_events. The code will work for you. It will be better if you use roleup summery than a trigger. refer @Marc answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(Id),AccountId FROM Opportunity 
 WHERE IsClosed = false and AccountId !=null Group By AccountId
```

try using this query.

Answer (score 0):

- List item

one one way is,you have to create custom field on Account like sahi__No_of_oppos__c(No of oppos),and write trigger on opportunity like whenever any dml is hapened,you have to update the field in Account (no of oppos).And the trigger will be like below.

```
trigger countingnoofopps on Opportunity (after insert, after delete,after undelete,after update) {

Set<Id> aId=new Set<Id>();

if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete){
for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){
aId.add(opp.AccountId);


}
List<Account> acc = [select id,sahi__No_of_oppos__c from Account where Id in:aId]; 

List<Opportunity > opportunity= [select id from Opportunity where AccountId in :aId ];

for(Account a :acc ){
a.sahi__No_of_oppos__c=opportunity.size();
}
update acc ;
}
if(Trigger.isDelete){
 for(opportunity opps : Trigger.old){
  aId.add(opps.AccountId); 
  } 
  List<Account> acc = [select id,sahi__No_of_oppos__c from Account where Id in:aId];
   List<Opportunity > opps= [select id from Opportunity where AccountId in :aId]; 
   for(Account a : acc){
    a.sahi__No_of_oppos__c=opps.size(); 
    }
    update acc; 
    }
if(Trigger.isUpdate){
 Set<Id> OldAId = new Set<Id>(); 
 for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){
  if(opp.AccountId != Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id).AccountId ) 
  aId.add(opp.AccountId); 
  OldAId.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id).AccountId); 
  }
   if(!aId.isEmpty()){ 
   //for new Accounts 
   List<Account> acc = [select id,sahi__No_of_oppos__c from Account where Id in:aId]; 
   //For New Account Contacts 
   List<Opportunity > con = [select id from Opportunity where AccountId in :aId]; 
   /* This is For Old Contacts Count */
    //for Old Accounts
     List<Account> Oldacc = [select id,sahi__No_of_oppos__c from Account where Id in:OldAId]; 
     //For Old Account Contacts
      List<Opportunity > OldCon = [select id from Opportunity where AccountId in :OldAId]; 
      //For New Accounts
       for(Account a : acc){ 
       a.sahi__No_of_oppos__c=con.size(); 
       }
       update acc; //For Old Accounts 
       for(Account a : Oldacc){
        a.sahi__No_of_oppos__c=OldCon.size();
         }
         update Oldacc;
          }
}
}
```

using the above trigger,you can get no of opportunity i didnt write filter criteria you can add according to your requirement.very simple.

Comment: thanq Ratan for editing,i tired to edit ,but not came like this.,

Comment: if my answer reached your requirement ,pls make as correct answer  rahulseth

Comment: i got it thanxx

Answer (score 0):

Using this query you can find Open Opportunity

SELECT Id,StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName !='CLosed Won' AND StageName !='Closed Lost'

Comment: Yes, you get Open Opportunities, but count you must yourself. And where is the relationship to Account? Etc.

Comment: Then you can use --- SELECT Id,AccountId ,StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName !='CLosed Won' AND StageName !='Closed Lost'

Comment: This does by no means answer the question of the OP.